# sumif, vlookup usage together

Tags: vba, excel

I think I am having a mental block this afternoon.

I have a sheet with - this sheet acts as a table with all codes. Column B in both sheets are a detailed description that I dont need, the second table may have a few rows or hundreds, this is just an example. The second sheet is a subset essentially of the first and I am just removing some granularity by adding column C to sum them up.

```
column A(unique code)   b     c
  1       abd    Wood
  2      rkger   Wood
  3a      egje   Concrete
  4      kepog   Metal
  5      kepog   Metal
```

2nd sheet

```
column A   b     c
  1       abd    4.5
  2      rkger   5.5
  3a      egje   5
  4      kepog   3
```

Basically i want to return

```
Wood      10
Concrete   5
Metal      3
```

I think I need a sumif and vlookup

Comment: Wierd.  since kepog is 3 for metal listed twice 3 is only summed once and not twice as it is for wood.  so you want a distinct b,c combo sum.

Comment: Add a column in the 2nd sheet with a vlookup back to the first sheet.  Then do a sumif on that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example data you provided (you can modify the rows to your needs).

In your **Column D** of *Sheet2*, put the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)
```

See Image below:
[image]

After, in order not to have a separate sheet, add in the bottom a Total section the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$5,D8,$C$2:$C$5)
```

See Image below:

[image]

Comment: `Column B in both sheets are a detailed description that I dont need` I think the OP wanted the two tables tied together on Column A, but this is the best method.